# How to print different glossaries entries with a common description

Tags: pdftex, glossaries, glossaries-extra

I would like to print different glossaries entries with a common description. For example, I can do this:

```
\newglossaryentry{s:rc} 
{
    name={\ensuremath{x', y', z'}},
    sort={s:rc}, 
    description={Rotated global coordinates associated with a bar}
}
```

The problem is that x' y' and z' are not different entries and I cannot print each one separately using \gls{}. I want to use \gls{} because it is a quick way to change a symbol for all the document. Obviously, I could use \newcommand to do the same, however, I think it is not the 'right' solution.

What I mean is that you can define commands of the form \newcommand{\x}{x'} and then use them throughout the document instead of using the glossaries package functionalities. There is a disadvantage however; if you want your glossary to show your s:rc entry you must print *all* the entries without sorting (at least this is what I understood).

So is there a proper way of doing it using the glossaries/glossaries-extra packages or not? In other words, is there a way to print different glossaries entries with a common description? Thank you!

I add some basic code as requested:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}  
\usepackage[sort = none]{glossaries-extra}
\newglossaryentry{s:i:p} 
{
    name={\ensuremath{\xi, \eta, \zeta}},
    sort={pi}, 
    description={Intrinsic coordinates of parent element}
}

\begin{document}
    I can Print all the entries using \gls{s:i:p}, but I have not control over the single entries. I can solve this using the command \verb!\newcommand!, however it does not seem a ``proper'' way of solving the problem. 
    
    \printunsrtglossary[style=long, title={List of Symbols}]
\end{document}
```

The result:
[image]

Comment: Your question leaves all the effort to us, even typing the essentials of a TeX document such as `\documentclass{}...\begin{document}` and the necessary package(s). As it is, you are left to the mercy of our procrastination team who are very few in number and very picky about selecting questions. Please improve your question by adding a MWE.

Comment: Sorry, I will add that.